# Non uniform data in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I recently come up with a requirement to develop an application that handles non-uniform data. Since I am not an expert person in databse design, i dont know what are the things to be taken care of or how it is done. Can some body explain the standard approach when dealing the non-uniform data. I am using MySql.

Edit: In my case,my data does not follow a structure. For ex. My application is an analytical site which performs a lot of calculations. It is used for audit purposes.But the audit standards's data structure will vary according to each standard.Which means,I can not fix a stabe table schema.

Comment: You're going to have to give examples. What does "non-uniform" data mean in this case?

Comment: @tadman..Thanks.Updated my question!

Comment: You might want to use a database like Postgres that supports schemaless datatypes like [native JSON columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html). MySQL doesn't have the same level of support for things like this, but it can be done if you're really determined.